# how to include "order by" in Pear MDB2 autoexecute select statments

Tags: php, sql, pear, mdb2

I'm using Pear MDB2's "Extended" module to have it automatically generate and execute SQL select statements.  The help document is here:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-auto.php

I want to get the results back from the DB in a certain order.  I know, I could have my PHP program do the sorting after the results are fetched, but it turns out to be much faster if the DB sorts it.

I can't find a way in the API to tell it to use "order by" and by which columns.  Is there a way to make MDB2 do this?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a way, unless it's undocumented. You'll just have to bite the bullet and write the queries by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the MDB2 extended module does not support ordering for autoprepared/executed queries.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer.  That sucks.

Comment: You might want to open a feature request.